# moving an array image left to right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am having an eight array image and two buttons left button , right button. when I click right button it should move to the next image. click left button move to the previous image.

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a1.png"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a7.png"];
UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a8.png"];
UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a3.png"];
UIImage *image5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a6.png"];
UIImage *image6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a2.png"];
UIImage *image7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a5.png"];
UIImage *image8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a9.png"];


NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1,image2,image3,image4,image5,image6,image7,image8,nil];


 numberOfViews = 8;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {

      [scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(numberOfViews * 31,0) animated:YES];
}
```

above coding I am just trying. when I click the button only one image is moving. what should I do.some one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property to your view controlled:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *sv;
```

Then in viewDidLoad, the following code creates a scroll view and adds 9 images to it, named like in your example. It also add two buttons below the scroll view, to go to previous/next images:

```
CGFloat width = 290;
CGFloat height = 290;
NSInteger imageCount = 9;

self.sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, width, height)];
self.sv.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.sv.pagingEnabled = YES;
self.sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width*imageCount, height);
[self.view addSubview:self.sv];

for (int i = 1; i <= imageCount; i++) {
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"a%d.png", i]]];
    imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    CGRect iFrame = imgView.frame;
    iFrame.origin.x = i * width;
    iFrame.origin.y = 0;
    iFrame.size.width = self.sv.frame.size.width;
    iFrame.size.height = self.sv.frame.size.height;
    imgView.frame = iFrame;
    [self.sv addSubview:imgView];
}


UIButton *previous = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[previous setTitle:@"Previous" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[previous addTarget:self action:@selector(previousImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[previous sizeToFit];
CGRect pFrame = previous.frame;
pFrame.origin.x = self.sv.frame.origin.x;
pFrame.origin.y = self.sv.frame.origin.y + self.sv.frame.size.height + 10;
previous.frame = pFrame;

UIButton *next = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[next setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[next addTarget:self action:@selector(nextImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[next sizeToFit];
CGRect nFrame = next.frame;
nFrame.origin.x = self.sv.frame.origin.x + self.sv.frame.size.width - nFrame.size.width;
nFrame.origin.y = self.sv.frame.origin.y + self.sv.frame.size.height + 10;
next.frame = nFrame;

[self.view addSubview:previous];
[self.view addSubview:next];
```

Then add the following methods to make the buttons do something:

```
- (void)nextImage:(UIButton *)sender {
    CGPoint p = self.sv.contentOffset;
    if (p.x + self.sv.frame.size.width <= self.sv.contentSize.width) {
        p.x += self.sv.frame.size.width;
        self.sv.contentOffset = p;
    }

}

- (void)previousImage:(UIButton *)sender {
    CGPoint p = self.sv.contentOffset;
    if (p.x - self.sv.frame.size.width >= 0) {
        p.x -= self.sv.frame.size.width;
        self.sv.contentOffset = p;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using story board? If I am understanding what you are asking. I would say just make a uiimageview named say displayImage, as well as an int count = 0 that both buttons can access. Have it load the image at images[0] when the app starts. Then when the right button is clicked have int count +1 if its is <= images.length. Then load images[count] to displayImage. Then when the left button is clicked have int count -1if it is >= 0. Then load images[count] to displayImage. Then just do this for all eight images. If you don't get it let me know and I can do the code out for you.

Comment: iam not using story board. please u can help me in coding.

Comment: i am just try the above code. u can help me in correct way in coding.

Comment: If the below doesn't work Lmk I am just Mobil right now sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

Take global int

In the leftbutton method, write i--;

In the rightbutton method, write i++;

```
if(i<0){

     i = 0;

   yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[yourImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
else if(i>yourImagesArray.count)
{
       i = youImagesArray.count;

    yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[yourImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];

}
 else 
 {
    yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[yourImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];

 }
```